# Is it possible to adb via wifi Direct?

Tags: adb, windows, wifi-direct

I have Wireless Adb, but really I'd like to be able to connect wirelessly to the phone when I'm out and about, and it's not possible to connect via a router.

Phone is CM Marshmellow, an s5.

Laptop is Windows 8.

Can I do this? How?

Comment: adb via WiFi you mean?

Comment: Wifi Direct. Wifi that doesn't have to go through a router. Same principle as Miracast, but instead of connecting a phone to a display dongle it will be connecting a phone to a computer, in such a way that the computer can send adb commands.

Comment: Here are my thoughts... if you don't want the connection via a router, would it be possible for you to create a local WiFi hotspot either from your Windows PC or mobile hotspot from your android device, then use adb via tcp or simple adb?

Comment: My carrier shuts me down if I do wifi hotspot from phone. From PC is a possibility though, I'll give it a go and report back. Thanks!

Comment: This may be helpful: [How to set up a network connection between Android phone and Windows PC without Internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175521/209414)