# Use wifi direct at 2.4GHz on Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: wifi-direct

I would like to configure my Galaxy Tab S2 to use the 2.4GHz frequency for WiFi direct because my PC doesn't support the 5GHz band. 
I'm using Total commander with the WiFi plugin to create a WebDAV server to be able to see the files on the tablet on the PC. This plugin can work by connecting to a wifi network but you can also use a wifi direct connection. My laptop is mostly in a room without a wifi connection, so  I would like to use the wifi direct option. However, it seems that this tablet only creates a 5Ghz wifi connection with WiFi direct.
Is it possible to configure it to use the 2.4Ghz band? How?

Comment: Possible? Yes it is but how technical do you want to get. It has been awhile since I have read up on wifi stuff. Is your question how to connect with wifi-direct at 2.4ghz? or you are having difficulty connecting at 2.4ghz? Because really all you have to do is connect to a 2.4ghz access point. Next go to the wifi-direct setting find the device you want to connect to and set up a pairing from that point on your should be good to go.

Comment: I explained in more detail what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Learning about wifi-direct (WD). Do you have a duel band router? Do you know which band the s2 was on when activating WD process? When connecting to an access point can you identify/isolate the network frequency of the SSID android wants to connect to? Or is your router configured to combine both frequencies under a single SSID. It appears connecting through a WiFi network. Android WD frequency is the same as its network connected wifi access point when creating a WD group. Once the group is created it should be a non-issue because the WD group conditions will be remembered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you are trying to use wi-fi direct to accomplish this task. AFAIK most Wi-Fi Direct compatible devices use the 2.4GHz connection  (by default) and given that most devices nowadays only communicate with other Wi-Fi Direct-certified devices not just random.

I suggest you simply use a standard wi-fi connection i.e something like a mobile hotspot using your device or [PC as host](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175521/209414). If it is a case that your mobile predominantly uses 5GHz connection, then you can [use this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2571129&d=1392048095) to force a 2GHz connection.

Another option apart from WebDAV server is using an SMB, FTP server or even TCP server of your folder structure in sdcard or internal storage [similar to this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167789).